# Pass loaded file variables as arguments to callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my new project, I am trying to avoid use of global variables using requirejs. I found that requirejs is using `define` and `require` methods to load supporting files. I am planning to write these methods on my own.

```
MyApp.loadFiles(['jquery', 'mustache'], function($, m){
   // my code using the above arguments
});
```

I know how to load files, but I don't know how to pass the loaded files variables as arguments to a callback function. and also I need to call this function when those files are completely loaded.

Please help with this.

Comment: Why do you want to redo all the work requireJS has done already?

Comment: I don't think I am doing all the work.. I am just trying to recreate a method from require which is `define`.

Comment: And then all the file download will be done by standard script src blocks?

Comment: Please add your code of file downloading if its short.